# Codeigniter: post is not working in form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am uploading images to "images" directory and some info to my database in codeigniter. But when I click to submit button after completing form, It posts nothing. It gives error that there is not posted any input(not the same as error message just meaning). If someone could please look over this code, and tell me why it's not working. Thank you in advance. Here my controller code:

```
<?php       
       public function create()
       {

            // image1
            $ImageName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $imageSize= $_FILES['image']['size'];
            $imageSource = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "images/$ImageName");
            $this->create_thumb($ImageName);
            $this->compress($ImageName, $imageSize, "images/$ImageName");

            // image2
            if ($this->input->post('image2'))
            {
                $ImageName2 = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
                $imageSize2= $_FILES['image2']['size'];
                $imageSource2 = $_FILES['image2']['tmp_name']; 
                $this->compress($ImageName2, $imageSize2, $imageSource2);
            }
            // image3
            if ($this->input->post('image3'))
            {
                $ImageName3 = $_FILES['image3']['name'];
                $imageSize3= $_FILES['image3']['size'];
                $imageSource3 = $_FILES['image3']['tmp_name']; 
                $this->compress($ImageName3, $imageSize3, $imageSource3);
            }
            // image4
            if ($this->input->post('image4'))
            {
                $ImageName4 = $_FILES['image4']['name'];
                $imageSize4= $_FILES['image4']['size'];
                $imageSource4 = $_FILES['image4']['tmp_name']; 
                $this->compress($ImageName4, $imageSize4, $imageSource4);
            }

            $this->news_model->set_news();
            $this->load->view('News/success');

    }

?>
```

Here my view code:

```
      <div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="content">
                        <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/news/create/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Сарлавха:</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Сарлавха">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Автомобил тури:</label>
                                        <select name="category" class="form-control">
                                                <option value="yuk">Юк</option>
                                                <option value="kichik">Кичик тижорат</option>       
                                                <option value="yengil">Енгил</option>
                                                <option value="maxsus">Махсус техника</option>
                                                <option value="tyagach">Тягач</option>
                                                <option value="prisep">Прицеп</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Нархи:</label>
                                        <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Нархи">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Исми ва шарифи:</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Исми ва шарифи">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Телефон рақам:</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="telno" class="form-control" value="+998" placeholder="Телефон рақам">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Жойи:</label>
                                        <select name="location" class="form-control">
                                                <option value="Қорақалпоғистон Республикаси">Қорақалпоғистон Республикаси</option>
                                                <option value="Бухоро вилояти">Бухоро вилояти</option>
                                                <option value="Жиззах вилояти">Жиззах вилояти</option>      
                                                <option value="Қашқадарё вилояти">Қашқадарё вилояти</option>
                                                <option value="Навоий вилояти">Навоий вилояти</option>
                                                <option value="Наманган вилояти">Наманган вилояти</option>
                                                <option value="Сурхондарё вилояти">Сурхондарё вилояти</option>
                                                <option value="Сирдарё вилояти">Сирдарё вилояти</option>
                                                <option value="Тошкент вилояти">Тошкент вилояти</option>
                                                <option value="Фарғона вилояти">Фарғона вилояти</option>
                                                <option value="Хоразм вилояти">Хоразм вилояти</option>
                                                <option value="Тошкент шаҳар">Тошкент шаҳар</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Қўшимча маълумот:</label>
                                        <textarea rows="5" name="info" class="form-control" placeholder="Қўшимча маълумот" ></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Асосий расмни танланг:</label>
                                        <input type="file" name='image' class="form-control" accept="image/*" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Қўшимча расмни танланг:</label>
                                        <input type="file" name='image2' class="form-control" accept="image/*" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Қўшимча расмни танланг:</label>
                                        <input type="file" name='image3' class="form-control" accept="image/*" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Қўшимча расмни танланг:</label>
                                        <input type="file" name='image4' class="form-control" accept="image/*" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right" name="submit" value="submit">Юклаш</button>
                            <div class="clearfix" ></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the controller should be surrounded by `Class news extends CI_Controller`

Comment: change the from action to this <?php echo base_url();?>/news/create/

Comment: try this so that you know that the file data is returning or not.`echo"<pre>";print_r($_FILE);exit;` this will print the file data.

Comment: @Tamil The first letter of the class name and file name should all ways be upper case only as explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Comment: You have to change your controller code like @Muhammad Usman defined  in their answer.

Comment: You have created simple function file that is not valid controller , You have to extends CI controller and follow their proper syntex

Answer (score 1):

Try this for debug first check $_FILES having any data.

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

If it has any data then trying to change condition like. Instead

```
if ($this->input->post('image2')){
```

Use following

```
if( isset( $_FILES['image']['name']) and $_FILES['image']['name'] != '' ) {
    // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller Should Be Like This

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

   class Controller_name extends CI_Controller{
   public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('your_model');
    $this->load->library('upload'); 
}

  public function function_name(){
        if($this->input->post('submit')){
      /* Your Function */

        }
  OR Use 
    if($_POST){
      /* Your Function */

        }

       $this->load->view('News/success');                                           
   }
```

- Controller Name Should Be Start From Capital Letter

Answer (score 0):

The  `if ($this->input->post('image3')){ /* ... */ }` is wrong. PHP will not see uploaded files.Check them as : `if (array_key_exists($_FILES, 'image3')){ /* ... */ }`